# Collateral damage after recovery (nvidia driver)

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

Made few attempts to install Nvidia driver. All unsuccessful, blackscreen. But that's not the matter.
Collateral damage was made to Ubuntu. After recovery I couldn't use HP function buttons for screen backlight, in power manager plugin slider for backlight disappeared and screen tearing is back.
Basically I want to revert everything to the state it was before nvidia-driver story.

So I'm asking for help to identify place(s) broken and how to fix them.

GK208M [GeForce GT 740M], Ubuntu 18.04.1

Purged nvidia like so (primus just in case, not sure it was there):

```
sudo apt purge nvidia* libnvidi* primus 
sudo apt autoremove
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

ls -l /sys/class/backlight

```
total 0
```

xrandr --verbose

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x2b1) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x2b0
    Timestamp:  50892
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
  1920x1080 (0x2b1) 159.667MHz *current
        h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

sudo lshw -c video

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff   
 *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3000000-d33fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
serpent_avx2           53248  0
serpent_avx_x86_64     53248  1 serpent_avx2
serpent_sse2_x86_64    57344  3
serpent_generic        28672  3 serpent_avx2,serpent_sse2_x86_64,serpent_avx_x86_64
lrw                    20480  3 serpent_avx2,serpent_sse2_x86_64,serpent_avx_x86_64
ablk_helper            16384  3 serpent_avx2,serpent_sse2_x86_64,serpent_avx_x86_64
dm_crypt               40960  2
ccm                    20480  6
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
uvcvideo               86016  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              184320  3 videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
arc4                   16384  2
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
iwldvm                229376  0
mac80211              778240  1 iwldvm
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             212992  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
aesni_intel           188416  6
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  4 serpent_avx2,serpent_sse2_x86_64,aesni_intel,serpent_avx_x86_64
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
cryptd                 24576  6 crypto_simd,ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
iwlwifi               282624  1 iwldvm
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
cfg80211              622592  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd                    81920  16 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_rawmidi
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
ie31200_edac           16384  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 usbhid,hid_generic
nouveau              1716224  0
i915                 1617920  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                   106496  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        172032  2 i915,nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               147456  0
ahci                   36864  2
drm                   401408  4 drm_kms_helper,i915,ttm,nouveau
r8169                  86016  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               65536  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    24576  4 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  45056  2 i915,nouveau
```

inxi -G

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: fbdev,intel (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.5
```

---

UPDATE : it was a blunder. Forgot to remove nomodeset from /etc/default/grub

Comment: Both graphics card are "unclaimed". You may need to start with reinstalling the Intel Graphics drivers. And removing previous Nvidia drivers can usually be done with only purge nvidia*... Where did you get those instructions from?

Comment: Don't think we can get you to the state " before nvidia-driver story", because we have no way to know what that state was. Do you know? Can you define it?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia instructions been collected across Internet. By the way had two libnvidia* files about 100mb each

Comment: At this point I would reinstall the OS and then install the recommended Nvidia driver with Additional Drivers. I agree with @mikewhatever, we have no way to know what that state was.

Comment: @mikewhatever sorry I wasn't clear enough. Rephrasing, to undo all changes made during nvidia drivers installation and following configurations etc